# Undefined is not an object(evaluating '_expo.default.Constants')

Tags: react-native, module, momentjs, expo

I am getting an error at `Constants` in `const{manifest}=Expo.Constants` and showing me an error as undefined is not an object. I am not able to get it. Can anyone help me in removing that error.

I am trying to make a connection between API running on my computer and when I am debugging on my phone. it should connect regardless of what the IP address is.

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import Expo from 'expo';

const{ manifest} = Expo.Constants;
const api = manifest.packagerOpts.dev
? manifest.debuggerHost.split(':').shift().concat(':3000')
: 'productionurl.com'

const url ='http://localhost:3000';

export function getEvents(){
    return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(events => events.map( e =>({...e})));
}
export function formatDateTime(dateString){
    const parsed = moment(new Date(dateString));

    if(!parsed.isValid()){
        return dateString;
    }

    return parsed.format('H A on DD MMM YYYY');
}
export function formatDate(dateString){
    const parsed = moment(new Date(dateString));

    if(!parsed.isValid()){
        return dateString;
    }

    return parsed.format('DD MMM YYYY');
}

export function getCountdownParts(eventDate){
    const duration = moment.duration(moment(new Date(eventDate)).diff(new Date()));
    return{
        days:parseInt(duration.as('days')),
    };
}
```

> Expected events to be displayed on my emulator from `db.json` file but
>   I am getting error as Undefined.

Answer (score 6):

## The following works for me:

### Instead of

```
import Expo from 'expo';
```

and (for example):

```
const { version } = Expo.Constants.manifest;
```

Which gave the above error,

### I wrote:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

and:

```
const { version } = Constants.manifest;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the error:

```
undefine is not an object (evaluating _expoLocation.default.reverseGeocodeAsync)
```

I solved it with an import change.

Before:

```
import Location from "expo-location";
```

After:

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.

```js
import { Constants as Manifest  } from 'expo';
```

Read how to use it for a detailed [description](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/).

Comment: I have tried the code you suggested but I am getting same error. @hong

Comment: Could you try this? `import * as Expo from "expo"`